# Pasting smaller image onto bigger image using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have the code written below (only a small portion of my code) and I want paste image2 above image1, but I don't want it to be the same size as image1 (1024x1024), how would I do this? I want image2 to be a smaller image on my entire picture, where image1 is the background, how would I do this? My smaller image has a res of 184x184, and my large image has a res of 1024x1024.

```
    image1 = Image.open('fab.png')
    image2 = Image.open('pfp.png')
    maskimg = Image.open('mask2.png')
    maskimg = maskimg.resize(image1.size)
    image2.paste(image1, (0,0,184,184), mask = maskimg)
    image1.save('merged_image.png')
```

I tried the code above, and expected it to work, but I got an error saying `ValueError: images do not match`

Comment: You need to add 3 images to your question to make a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you want to paste image2 as a 184x184 image on top of image1, you first have to resize image2 to those dimensions. Note the double parentheses to make sure the function `resize()` has only one input argument which is a tuple:

```
image2 = Image.open('pfp.png').resize((184, 184))
```